# 20th derivative of a rational function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, rational-functions

I could not find the 20th derivative of the function below :

$$f(x) = \frac{2x}{x^2 - 4}$$

I have taken 1st and 2nd derivatives but I could not succeed at generalizing the derivative function.

Comment: Do you mean $$\frac{2x}{x^2 - 4}$$?

Comment: yeah, i mean the function that you write

Comment: Have you tried partial fractions?

Comment: is like taking the 20th derivative of $1/x$ and use partial fraction and linearity of derivative operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we have $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-2}+\frac{1}{x+2}$ then we get $$f'(x)=- \left( x-2 \right) ^{-2}- \left( x+2 \right) ^{-2}$$ $$f''(x)=2\, \left( x-2 \right) ^{-3}+2\, \left( x+2 \right) ^{-3}$$ $$f'''(x)=-6\, \left( x-2 \right) ^{-4}-6\, \left( x+2 \right) ^{-4}$$
can you proceed?
for your control the answer is $$f(x)^{(20)}=2432902008176640000\, \left( x-2 \right) ^{-21}+2432902008176640000\,
 \left( x+2 \right) ^{-21}
$$

Comment: You could have written that big number as $20!$

Comment: yes thank you for your hint, have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:-**

Decompose the given fraction into Partial Fraction and then use the following identity,$$y=\dfrac{1}{x} \implies y^{(n)}=(-1)^nn!\left(\dfrac{1}{x^{n+1}}\right)$$

**Hint to a proof of the identity:-**

> Apply Induction.